# Spring JdbcTemplate Query returns empty List instead of Exception

Tags: spring

While I was running a Junit Test for my DAO Method i stumbled upon this:

If I run my autowired JdbcTemplate like:
`jdbcTemplate.query(myStatement, new MyRowMapper(), myParam1, myParam2)` and the resultSet is empty, my Junit Test passes, because `MyRowMapper` was not called.

When the resultSet is NOT empty my Junit Test fails with a `SQLException` because `MyRowMapper` is trying to access a non existing Column in the `ResultSet`.

The problem is my SQL Statement is wrong in combination with `MyRowMapper` but depending on my two params, at one time I get an empty `ResultSet` and my Test is fine and the other time the test fails because there are records waiting to be mapped by the `RowMapper`.

So my question is: How can I (best practice?) junit test the `jdbcTemplate().query(String sql, RowMapper<Systemgruppe> rowMapper, Object... args)` method to verify that the SQL Statement is valid AND (!) the `RowMapper` can handle it no matter if there are records or not?

We use spring-core version: 4.3.7.RELEASE

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why should it throw an exception on an empty result? And why should it call the `RowMapper` if there are no rows to map.

Comment: I understand that if the resultset is empty there is nothing to map so the rowmapper must not be called. I just wanted to know how i can unit test this query method the best way to verify that the sql statement works with the rowmapper in every way. What i miss is something like "ok you gave me a valid Statement and a RowMapper, but i must warn you that your Rowmapper is mapping a column i don't see in your Statement no matter if your resultset has records or not"